# Which is correct in this context "are that of a" or "came to be from"?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

Could you please tell me which one of the following sentences is correct?

1. It is strongly believed to this day that all butterflies flying over fields, meadows, parks and gardens **are that of a young widow's** scrap of dress.
2. It is strongly believed to this day that all butterflies flying over fields, meadows, parks and gardens **came to be from the young widow's** scrap of dress.

Comment: If the story is about just one young widow, "It is strongly believed to this day that all butterflies flying over fields, meadows, parks and gardens came from the young widow's scrap of dress."  If there are many young widows, "... a young widow's scrap of dress," because "the" here requires a unique reference.

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling that the first sentence made little sense. I think I found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the expression **...that of a...**, **that** represents a single item, normally the subject of the first clause.

> The painting is that of a 16th century Dutch merchant 
>   The painting is [a painting] of a 16th century Dutch merchant

**that** therefore doesn't work at all in your first sentence, as butterflies are plural and, even it **those** were used instead, it would mean

> are [butterflies] of a young widow's scrap of dress.

The second sentence makes more sense and is grammatically correct, however the words **to be** are unnecessary and confusing, even in a literary context.

The use of **the** implies that there is one particular widow, and she was referred to in previous sentences. This might work if this is the final sentence in a story abouut a widow.

If the sentence is intended to work on its own, it would be necessary to replace **the** by **a**.

Comment: I believe 'came to be' here was meant as a synonym for 'came into existence'. 'Came to be from a dress' sounds awkward, though.

Answer (score -1):

It is strongly believed to this day that all butterflies flying over fields, meadows, parks and gardens are that of a young widow's scrap of dress

The sentence simply means that the butterflies belonged to the dress of a young widow. simply put, the dress owned the butterflies.

It is strongly believed to this day that all butterflies flying over fields, meadows, parks and gardens came to be from the young widow's scrap of dress.

This sentence means that the butterflies were born of or were made from a dress of a young widow.